# Shared counter between enumerate and equations

Tags: equations, lists, enumerate, counters

I'm currently writing some math stuff in LaTeX and I've encountered the following problem: I'd like to have "shared" counters in equations and specific lists, s.t. for example

```
\begin{equation}
    a + b = c
\end{equation}
and additionally
\begin{mycoolenum}
    \item $c + d = e$
    \item $c - f = e$
\end{mycoolenum}
```

results in

```
(1.1)      a + b = c

and additionally
    (1.2) c + d = e
    (1.3) c + f = e
```

The reason why I want to do this is to have consistent reference names throughout my work. I've tried playing around with [resume] and the list enviornment but to no avail.

What it should kinda look like:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{equation}
        a + b = c
    \end{equation}
    \begin{list}{\theequation}{}
        \addtocounter{equation}{1}
        \item $c + d = e$
        \addtocounter{equation}{1}
        \item $c - f = e$
    \end{list}
    \begin{equation}
        1 + 1 = 2
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: To clarify: I'm currently using `flalign` to somewhat imitate the desired behavior, but this has some disadvantages regarding both code and the final result.

Comment: why not just use an `align` for the *list* which isn't actually a list.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that: I am currently using `flalign` to somewhat imitate a list environment, the problem there is that there are quite a few differences in the "look" (e.g. the position of the labels, text-rich items look very funky in the code due to many `\text` commands) and it feels very hack-ish ;)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Megge, perhaps you should structure your source better. If it is formulas, then treat them at formulas. Don't use homemade approximations just because it *feels easier*. E.g. don't write `\text{ for all } x>0 \text{ and } y\pm 1`. Write `\qquad\text{for all $x>0$ and $y\pm1$}`, then the structure is better and the entire *for* part is marked as *extra information*. Lots of users could benefit from structuring their source more appropriately.

Comment: Maybe I should give you an example use case, sorry! Lets say I have a theorem that says "Operator A has following properties under following assumptions", and I list them inside this enumeration. Later in the proof I want to write "with assumption (1.2) and equation (1.4) this and this follows".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `equation` counter for the enumerated list, just take care of not resetting it or, better, to set it at the correct value.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newcounter{keepeqno}
\newenvironment{mycoolenum}
 {\setcounter{keepeqno}{\value{equation}}%
  \begin{list}{(\theequation)}{\usecounter{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{keepeqno}}}
 {\end{list}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{equation}
a + b = c
\end{equation}
\begin{mycoolenum}
\item $c + d = e$
\item $c - f = e$
\end{mycoolenum}
\begin{equation}
1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea to the question in: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638215/how-to-make-text-align-left-in-the-new-enumerate-environment/638343#638343

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it again the solution was kinda obvious:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\let\Item\item
\newenvironment{mlist}{\renewcommand{\item}{\refstepcounter{equation} \Item} \begin{list}{\theequation}{}}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{equation}
        a + b = c
    \end{equation}
    \begin{mlist}
        \item $c + d = e$
        \item $c - f = e$
    \end{mlist}
    \begin{equation}
        1 + 1 = 2
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This gives the desired result.

Comment: With your current solution you can't nest list environments. I think the redefinition of `item` can be avoided if you use: `\begin{list}{\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation}}`

Comment: (I changed soemthing since you commented) The problem is that apparently the "\ref value" gets overridden by `\item` in your example, so references to "(2.1), (2.2), (2.3)" change to "(2.1), (2.1), (2.1)". `\usecounter` doesn't work either, as this resets the counter every call. With the current code it works, but I'm not sure how "clean" this is

Comment: The issue is that the optional argument of `item` overwrites the behaviour of `\refstepcounter`.