# How to set the item space of a new enumerate environment?

Tags: spacing, enumerate

For personal use, I new two kinds of enumerate environments: one is the default for which I did some setting as follows, and one new enumerate environment which shares counter with equations using [@egreg 's way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121033/140814). I also set the `enumerate item` space, but the `my enumerate item` space don't change.

**Then how to improve the following codes to make the `my enumerate item` space be the small as `enumerate item` space defined?**

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
%set item space----------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1,2,3]{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt}
\setitemize[1,2,3]{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt}
\setdescription{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt}
%set item indent----------------------------------------------------
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=1.7em}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=1.05em}
%define a new enumerate share counter with equation-----------------------
\newcounter{keepeqno}
\newenvironment{myenumerate}
{\setcounter{keepeqno}{\value{equation}}%
    \begin{list}{(\theequation)}{\usecounter{equation}}%
        \setcounter{equation}{\value{keepeqno}}}
    {\end{list}}
%let equation enumerate with section------------------------------------
\numberwithin{equation}{section}%
%set equation number format------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}%
%allow align linebreak------------------------------------------------
\allowdisplaybreaks
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Apple
\item Pear
\item Watermelon
\end{enumerate}

\begin{myenumerate}
\item Apple
\item Pear
\item Watermelon
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: added a second solution.

Add

```
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
```

to the list environment:

```
\newenvironment{myenumerate}
{\setcounter{keepeqno}{\value{equation}}%
    \begin{list}{(\theequation)}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\usecounter{equation}}%
        \setcounter{equation}{\value{keepeqno}}}
    {\end{list}}
```

And here is another solution withe the `\newlist` command from the `enumitem` package:

```
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{label={(\theequation)},align=left,labelwidth=*,
  itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,
  before={\setcounter{keepeqno}{\value{equation}}\usecounter{equation}},
  first={\setcounter{equation}{\value{keepeqno}}}}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the length parameters are not inherited from the `enumerate` environment, so I had to copy/paste them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! To make `myenumerate item` space be completely same as `enumerate item` space, I revised your codes.

Comment: Do you have any idea to the problem in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638215/how-to-make-text-align-left-in-the-new-enumerate-environment/638230?noredirect=1#comment1591051_638230

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line

`\setenumerate[1,2,3]{itemsep`=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt}

in:

```
\setenumerate[1,2,3]{itemsep=12pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt}
```

And you have the following output:

[image]

EDIT: After your comment, chabge the code for the second list:

```
\begin{myenumerate}
\vspace{-10pt}\item Apple
\vspace{-10pt}\item Pear
\vspace{-10pt}\item Watermelon
\end{myenumerate}
```

and you have the desired result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! But it's not a global answer that I have to adjust the space for every `myenumerate`.