# How to make text align left in the new enumerate environment enumerated uniformly with equations?

Tags: equations, align, enumerate

First a MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}%
\newcounter{keepeqno}
\newenvironment{myenumerate}
{\setcounter{keepeqno}{\value{equation}}%
    \begin{list}{(\theequation)}
        {\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\usecounter{equation}}%
        \setcounter{equation}{\value{keepeqno}}}
    {\end{list}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
The equation is
\begin{equation}
f(x)=x^2+3x+9.
\end{equation}
It satisfies the following conditions.
\begin{myenumerate}
\item Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic. Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic. Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic.
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

And the appearance of the compiled PDF is as follows.

[image]

As you see, I defined a new enumerate environment in which *items are enumerated together with equations in the section* (please see [the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637853/how-to-set-the-item-space-of-a-new-enumerate-environment/637864#637864) for the reason to define such a new enumerate environment), and the texts in item (1.2) are aligned left while those in item (1.10) are not. **Then how to make texts in item (1.10) are also aligned left?**

Comment: Off-topic: Running `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}` is not a good idea, as it doesn't imply that the `equation` counter will be reset to zero whenever a `\section` directive occurs. `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` already accomplishes this; why run `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}` as well?

Comment: @Pieter van Oostrum may have some ideas?

Comment: @egreg may have some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}%
\newcounter{keepeqno}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{label={(\theequation)},
align=left,labelwidth=\widthof{(9.99)},leftmargin=!,
itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,
before={\setcounter{keepeqno}{\value{equation}}\usecounter{equation}},
first={\setcounter{equation}{\value{keepeqno}}}}
  

\begin{document}
  
\section{Test}
The equation is
\begin{equation}
f(x)=x^2+3x+9.
\end{equation}
It satisfies the following conditions.
\begin{myenumerate}
\item Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic. Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic. Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic.
\end{myenumerate}
The equation is
\begin{equation}
f(x)=x^2+3x+9.
\end{equation}
It satisfies the following conditions.
\begin{myenumerate}
\item Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic. Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic. Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic.
\end{myenumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Corrected. Now with a complete MWE, that gives the correct results.

Comment: Thanks very much! And I simplified the codes! By the way, in fact I've tried one or two of `align=left,labelwidth=\widthof{(9.99)},leftmargin=!` but not all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest that you *not* create a list-like environment from scratch. Instead, I'd like to suggest that you load the `enumitem` package and employ its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros to create a bespoke enumerate-like list.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}%

\usepackage{enumitem} % see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label=(\arabic{equation}.\arabic*),noitemsep}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{equation}

\begin{myenum}
\item Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic. Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Some texts.
\item Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic. Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic.
\end{myenum}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose doing it with `enumitem` ;

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}%
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[myenumerate]{label =(\thesection.\arabic*), wide=0pt, labelsep=3pt, widest=11, leftmargin=*}

    \begin{document}

    \section{Test}
    \begin{myenumerate}
    \item Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic. Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic.
    \item Some texts.
    \item Some texts.
    \item Some texts.
    \item Some texts.
    \item Some texts.
    \item Some texts.
    \item Some texts.
    \item Some texts.
    \item Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic. Belonging to a hereditary class with high social or political status; aristocratic.
    \end{myenumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! While the answer is similar to @Mico.

Comment: To a certain extent, yes, but I forgot to look at other answers when I posted mine – and great minds think together ;o).

Comment: Your new environment shares no numbers with equations.

Comment: I changed it because I didn't understand what equation numbers had to do here. But if you really need them, you can replace the definition of label with `label=(\arabic{equation}.\arabic*)`.