Putting an enumerated list on an equation counter
I would like to put certain enumerated lists on the same counter as my displayed equations. Can anyone suggest how I can do this?
Close to minimal working example below.
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} 
\parskip=5pt  
\parindent=0pt  

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{My section} 
\subsection{My subsection}

This is an equation that I want to display:
\begin{equation}\label{first}
\mbox{An equation I want to display.}
\end{equation}

I like to be able to refer to \eqref{first}.

Sometimes I like to make normal enumerated lists. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item So interesting. 
\item Also interesting. 
\end{enumerate}

But sometimes, I like to make an enumerated lists that formatted the same way as displayed equations.  
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{second} First enumerated fact. 
\item \label{third} Second enumerated fact. 
\item \label{fourth} Third enumerated fact.
\end{enumerate} 

And then I want to refer to \eqref{third} the same way that I refer to \eqref{first}. 

\end{document} 

I would like to be able to set it up so that the entries in the second list are labeled (1.2), (1.3), (1.4), styled the same as the displayed equation (1.1).

Ah: Ideally I would add a little pdf of the latex code I provided above. Any suggestions about how to do that?

(Also, this is not my first rodeo here but I've stopped trying to control my accounts ever since MathOverflow joined mine and my spouse's separate accounts because we occasionally used the same computer. But rest assured my other questions were much in the same spirit.)

Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121020/82917

@campa It's perfect! Thank you! (Contrary to what it looks like, I did search for this, both here and online, multiple times. But you searched better!) Can't upvote sadly it seems in this incarnation. But happy to accept your answer if you want to bother making one. Otherwise I can just close.

Ok, wait. It looks like with this trick (of saving the equation counter in a new counter, and then making an enumerated list environment using that counter) doesn't play well with the enumitem spacing commands... Makes sense, since it's a separate environment, but not ideal.

The following ports the answer that campa pointed out to use the \newlist formulation defined by the enumitem package, and so will be compatible with its spacing commands, following OP's request.
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{eqenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[eqenum]{before=\setcounter{eqenumi}{\value{equation}},after=\setcounter{equation}{\value{eqenumi}},label=(\thesection.\arabic*),ref=\thesection.\arabic*}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} 
\parskip=5pt  
\parindent=0pt  

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{My section} 
\subsection{My subsection}

This is an equation that I want to display:
\begin{equation}\label{first}
\mbox{An equation I want to display.}
\end{equation}

I like to be able to refer to \eqref{first}.

Sometimes I like to make normal enumerated lists. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item So interesting. 
\item Also interesting. 
\end{enumerate}

But sometimes, I like to make an enumerated lists that formatted the same way as displayed equations.  
\begin{eqenum}
\item \label{second} First enumerated fact. 
\item \label{third} Second enumerated fact. 
\item \label{fourth} Third enumerated fact.
\end{eqenum} 

And then I want to refer to \eqref{third} the same way that I refer to \eqref{first}. 


\end{document}

Notes:

The statement \newlist{eqenum}{enumerate}{1} tells enumitem to create a new enumerated list that can only be used at the first level (you cannot have nested ones of it).
The before and after keys of enumitem can be used to copy the equation counter to the counter used for the eqenum list and vice versa. After which I just used the label and ref keys to set the appearance of labels. The two should be set separately since I assume you want the labels to appear as (1.3) and want \eqref{third} to show (1.3) and not ((1.3)).


You want \setcounter{eqenumi}{\value{equation}}, rather than \arabic.

@egreg: thanks, as always.

I don't have enough rep here to upvote -- but I am quite grateful, both to you and to @campa.

This worked great... until I ended up with a numbered equation in the middle (of an item) of such a special enumerated list. Any ideas about how this could fly? @egreg

Uh my first inclination is to say "don't do that". Semantically that doesn't make sense: it is like asking for one numbered equation to be a part of another numbered equation. // But if you must, then you should do so by aliasing the counter instead of copying it. egreg's answer shows a pretty clean way to do so.

You can make a new list like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/715751/4427, but making the counter to be equation.
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{eqenum}{enumerate}{1}
\makeatletter\let\c@eqenumi\c@equation\makeatother
\setlist[eqenum]{
  resume,
  label=(\theequation),
  ref=\theequation,
  before=\stepcounter{equation},
  after=\addtocounter{equation}{-1},
}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{My section} 
\subsection{My subsection}

This is an equation that I want to display:
\begin{equation}\label{first}
\mbox{An equation I want to display.}
\end{equation}

I like to be able to refer to \eqref{first}.

Sometimes I like to make normal enumerated lists. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item So interesting. 
\item Also interesting. 
\end{enumerate}

But sometimes, I like to make an enumerated lists that formatted the same way as displayed equations.  
\begin{eqenum}
\item \label{second} First enumerated fact. 
\item \label{third} Second enumerated fact.
  \begin{equation} a+b=c \end{equation}
\item \label{fourth} Third enumerated fact.
\end{eqenum} 

And then I want to refer to \eqref{third} the same way that I refer to \eqref{first}. 


But sometimes, I like to make an enumerated lists that formatted the same way as displayed equations.  
\begin{eqenum}
\item \label{second-A} First enumerated fact. 
\item \label{third-A} Second enumerated fact.
  \begin{equation} a+b=c \end{equation}
\item \label{fourth-A} Third enumerated fact.
\end{eqenum} 

And then I want to refer to \eqref{third} the same way that I refer to \eqref{first}. 

\end{document}



Thanks. This part did work. However, now I'm getting some weird side effect (where despite the "numberwithin" command sometimes the equation counter is reset at the beginning of a section and sometimes not). But of course my document is a lot more complicated than this here; I probably have an additional weird linkage that's affecting things. (In fact, I know I do: my theorems etc. are on the same counter as equations. But that doesn't actually appear to explain what's happening.) If I'm feeling strong, I'll put together an MWE. In any case, thank you.
